# Jqtransform Issue classes not getting applied to select boxes

Tags: magento, jqtransform

I am using the Jqtransform Plugin in Magento for forms. When the payment section gets reloaded by AJAX on the checkout page, none of the jqtransform classes are applied to it. Do I need to add the script anywhere in the JavaScript? I am using the onestepcheckout extension.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that if ajax reload happens your dom parts are replaced with new ones and Jqtransform plugin has not replaced the new parts that are loaded and aplied to dom. You need to recall or reinit the Jqtransform calls on each load or dom replacement.